# Trying to use a range to create sequence in csv file but just get the last number in the sequence

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv which includes for each row a beginning street number and an end street number. I want to expand the csv rows to include a street address for every number in the range. I get the correct number of new rows but each row has the last number in the sequence. I have used the following code:

```py
import os
import csv
work_dir = r'###filepath###'
os.chdir(work_dir)
infname = r'###csv file###.csv'

rows = []
newRows = []
infile = open(infname)
infile_csv = csv.DictReader(infile)
for row in infile_csv:
    rows.append(row)

for row in rows:
    no1 = int(row['House_No._From'])
    no2 = int(row['House_No._To'])+1
    textSuffix = row['Street_Name'] 
    rangeOfStrNo = list(range(no1, no2))
    for r in rangeOfStrNo:
        newAddress = str(r) + " " + str(textSuffix)
        row['cat_l1_add'] = newAddress
        newRows.append(row)
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thank you AMC, I have removed the images and minimized it a bit. I think I can get rid off the first half by replacing the input with a dictionary, I just have to do some googling to brush up on how to do that first. Cheers

Comment: You no longer need any help?

Comment: No, it still does not work.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to replicate this problem with an ordered dictionary. I think that this is as much as I can minimize it.

Comment: We’re still missing some things for this to be a [mcve] though, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code is putting the *same* dictionary in each row of `newRows`, so the last value assigned to it is what ends up in all references to it. To avoid the that, just make a separate a copy of it before making modifications.

```
import os
import csv

work_dir = r'.'
os.chdir(work_dir)
infname = r'house_addrs.csv'

rows = []
newRows = []
infile = open(infname, 'r', newline='')  # PROPER WAY TO OPEN CSV FILE.
infile_csv = csv.DictReader(infile)
for row in infile_csv:
    rows.append(row)
infile.close()  # Don't forget to close the file.

for row in rows:
    no1 = int(row['House_No._From'])
    no2 = int(row['House_No._To'])+1
    textSuffix = row['Street_Name']
    rangeOfStrNo = list(range(no1, no2))
    for r in rangeOfStrNo:
        rowCopy = row.copy()  #### MAKE A COPY ####
        newAddress = str(r) + " " + str(textSuffix)
        rowCopy['cat_l1_add'] = newAddress
        newRows.append(rowCopy)
```